# How do I use a headset with 3.5mm jack on my PS4 while using a mouse & keyboard?

Tags: ps4, fortnite-battle-royale

I want to use my mouse and keyboard on PS4, but not sure how I would use my headset. I saw someone that used a multi port and a usb headset but I would rather use the ones I have. Can I use my headphones through my controller while using louse & keyboard? (Controller connected but not being used, just for audio purposes)

Answer (score 2):

In the event where the controller's port doesn't work with keyboard and mouse connected, you can use a USB to 3.5mm adapter, [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I5P3POO) [has](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XP5R449) [several](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07D4C5JLF) options and eBay as well.